# How to implement a client registration form providing additional dynamically-generated fields using jQuery and Asp.Net MVC 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a registration form for a sport competition using Asp.net MVC 3 (Razor view engine).

Each school can have only one team consisting of at most 20 members plus 1 team leader.

The team leader has to register the members by filling in the registration form I provide.

Rather than displaying 20 sets of member fields, it is a good idea if I can provide a button `Add One More Member` to render an additional set of member fields. This mechanism behaves like `Add file` when you want to attach one more file in Yahoo mail.

Shortly speaking, I have no idea:

1. Is there a mature implementation of jQuery available to implement a form providing additional dynamically-generated form fields?
2. How to implement this scenario in Asp.net MVC 3? How to manage the unknown number of posted form fields?

### Edit

Each member has 4 fields:

1. FirstName (string)
2. LastName (string)
3. BirthDate (datetime)
4. Photograph (image file)

Comment: You just mean a dynamic set of attachments?  Or you have additional fields like MiddleName or something?

Answer (score 4):

use a form collection in your controller if you don't know the names:

```
public ActionResult(FormCollection formFields)
{
        return View();
}
```

or if you have something like a bunch of team member input textboxes you could give them all the same name and then have an array or list as the parameter:

```
public ActionResult(String[] teamMembers)
{
        return View();
}
```

Further still you can do this with objects:

```
<input type="textbox" name="TeamMember[0].FirstName" />
<input type="textbox" name="TeamMember[0].LastName" />
<input type="textbox" name="TeamMember[1].FirstName" />
<input type="textbox" name="TeamMember[1].LastName" />
```

and then in your controller

```
public ActionResult(List<TeamMember> teamMemberList)
{
        return View();
}
```